# Cannot dynamically update UI Grid Class Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

I've been trying to get my UIAPP grid to dynamically add objects based on a button insert button but cannot seem to do so.  I don't know why this isn't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function trackColumns() 
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(500).setHeight(360).setTitle('Step 1:  Select Information to Track');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("settingsPanel");
  var headerpanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("headerPanel").setStyleAttribute("background", "silver").setWidth(500);
  var columnPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var mainGrid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId("mainGrid");
  var columnGrid =app.createGrid(1,1).setId("columnGrid");
  var columnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("columnspanel");
  var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText("Name");
  columnspanel.add(columnname);
  var addcolumnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("addcolumnspanel");
  var addbuttonhandler = app.createServerHandler("addcolumn");
  addbuttonhandler.addCallbackElement(columnGrid);
  var addbutton = app.createButton().setId("btnaddcolumn").setText("Add another column").addClickHandler(addbuttonhandler);  
  addcolumnspanel.add(addbutton);   
   columnGrid.setWidget(0, 0, columnspanel);
   mainGrid.setWidget(1, 0, columnGrid);
   mainGrid.setWidget(2, 0, addcolumnspanel);
   panel.add(mainGrid);
   app.add(panel);
   ss.show(app);
   return app;
}


function trackster_addcolumn(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var columnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("columnspanel");
  var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText("Name");
  var columntype = app.createListBox();
  columntype.addItem("Text");
  columntype.addItem("DropDown");
  columntype.addItem("Date");
  columntype.addItem("Number");
  columnspanel.add(columnname);
  columnspanel.add(columntype);
  var columngrid = e;
  columngrid.setWidget(3,0,columnspanel);
  return app; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell...

Would need to initialize this grid for 4 rows if you're wanting to set some thing in (3,0) later in the server function.

`var columnGrid =app.createGrid(1,1).setId("columnGrid");` >> `var columnGrid =app.createGrid(4,1).setId("columnGrid");`

Server function name just needs to match what's in the createServerHandler()...

`function trackster_addcolumn(e)` >> `function addcolumn(e)`

e has the values of all the widgets passed through to the server function, not the actual widgets themselves.  To get grid...

`var columngrid = e;` >> `var columngrid = app.getElementById('columngrid');`

Comment: Yes the trackster issue was just because I typed some/copied some.  The grid is set to be larger. 

var mainGrid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId("mainGrid");

Comment: The error I keep getting is

Error encountered: Cannot find function setWidget in object [object Object].

Comment: Forgot to add the getElementByID.  Now if only there were a way to detect how many columns already exist in the grid!

Comment: The flexPanel is better for dynamic stuff than grid